# Marketing Cloud Connector integration with Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Anyone ever run into this issue? Here’s what happened. Salesforce connector just finished integration last week. Everything worked - I set up objects to sync, they were syncing just fine (synchronized data extensions were created and populating). Then, for some reason it stopped working due to a number of IP addresses not being whitelisted.

No objects would sync and we could not add new objects.

I had client whitelist all IPs, and then after sometime, still not working, going into Salesforce Integration, we see this. Account is disconnected. Customer goes to reconnect and inputs the sales cloud credentials and gets this error. [image]

Comment: You would be missing a setup process or a potential configuration that was missed, I would re-run through the entire configuration process step by step from the following documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_connect_the_clouds.htm&type=5, this should fix your issue, the errors in Marketing Cloud are too vague to perform a process of elimination so therefore it will be quicker to re-run through the setup process.

Comment: I agree with @thechrishaddad that it's likely a misstep in configuration. I'd also recommend the trailhead for this module in addition to the docs they posted https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect. As a side note, I've encountered this before as well and resetting the connector resolved the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem last month: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289177/salesforce-integration-an-exception-occurred-while-saving-the-integration

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 common causes for such error messages

1- [ConnectedApp Authentication is not properly configured in Sales Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_set_up_authentication.htm&type=5)

2- [The Salesforce System user does not have the correct configuration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_set_up_salesforce_system_user.htm&type=5)

3- [There are IP restrictions in place within the Org or the IP Ranges for Salesforce Managed Packages have not been whitelisted](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_whitelist_ip_addresses_for_salesforce_managed_packages.htm&type=5)

4- (Less likely)- The "Is Sandbox" checkbox is not checked if Connecting to Sandbox environment.

I hope that helps.
Cheers.