# SFMC to SFDC integration issue via Marketing Cloud Connect: 'Remote Access 2.0 Failed: Missing Consumer Key Parameter'

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, marketing-cloud

When following the steps here - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/finish-mc-connect-configuration- I am hitting this error in SFMC when trying to connect SFMC to SFDC:

'An exception occurred while saving the integration.'

[image]

Looking at the login history of the Salesforce System admin user, I see these entries:

[image]

I have double checked that the Connected App 'Salesforce settings look correct and they are setup as outlined in the Trailhead module.

Everything looks correct to me - I followed the Marketing Cloud Connect startup wizard and selected the 'automatic' settings. In Setup | Network, I even see the IP address in the System user login entry listed there too so I am also unsure why it's saying 'Restricted IP'.

Do I need to restart everything from scratch? This is the only advice I can seem to find about how to resolve issues of this nature: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337425&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Hi Andy - removing the Config doesn't actually mean starting from scratch - try it, and if it doesn't work, open a support case. Had a similar issue few months back: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289177/salesforce-integration-an-exception-occurred-while-saving-the-integration. I hope you're on Premier, because solving it with Standard took me three weeks

Comment: Thanks - I tried everything in that link but nothing worked. I'll raise a support ticket. Thanks

Comment: I believe that the issue is if the Profile you are using has Login IP restrictions, then even if the IP addresses are in Setup | Network as part of the automatic setup wizard, you'll hit this error. I have changed the Login IP restrictions of the System User and this is now working.